# The maximum number of element in a list when generate all the permutations of a list in Python

Tags: python, permutation

I am using itertools to generate all the permutations of a Python list

```
import itertools
lt = [0,1,2,3]
print list(set(itertools.permutations(lt)))
```

it works good when the length of the list is less than 7, when length of list is grater than 7 ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]), it takes a lot of time to generate all the permutations, and the program is frozen. So I am wondering if there is any way to generate all the permutations for a big list, thank you!

Comment: The number of permutations of a list of `n` elements is `n!`, which grows quite quickly. It seems to me that you are after only the unique permutations (from your use of `list(set(...))`. Unless you have duplicate elements in your list (which it doesn't seem like you do), that `list(set(...))` is unnecessary. You might be able to save on /some/ time by ignoring them

Comment: @alfasin: it also depends on which version of python you use. Python2.7 for instance, allocates memory for, and computes the entire permutation list. Python3.x on the other hand computes each next iteration when required

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: What? No, `permutations` has always returned an iterator.

Comment: @alfasin: When I try it on Python 2, it also takes milliseconds. I don't know why you're getting such a huge runtime.

Comment: @user2357112 my bad, the huge amount of time is due to sublime text... running it from shell returns immediately! Not sure why sublime is so slow...

Comment: You're right. I had it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools` return a generator in `ns` time. It's slow to do the conversion `set()`.

**8!**

```
>>> lt = [i for i in xrange(8)]
>>> %timeit itertools.permutations(lt)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 547 ns per loop

>>> %timeit set(itertools.permutations(lt))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop

>>> %timeit list(set(itertools.permutations(lt)))
10 loops, best of 3: 19.1 ms per loop

>>> %timeit list(itertools.permutations(lt))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.9 ms per loop
```

**9! = 362880**

```
>>> lt = [i for i in xrange(9)]

>>> %timeit itertools.permutations(lt)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 557 ns per loop

>>> %timeit set(itertools.permutations(lt))
1 loops, best of 3: 167 ms per loop

>>> %timeit list(set(itertools.permutations(lt)))
1 loops, best of 3: 186 ms per loop

>>> %timeit list(itertools.permutations(lt))
10 loops, best of 3: 61.9 ms per loop
```

Compared with a `for`loop generate a list with length(362880)

```
>>> %timeit list(i for i in xrange(362880))
10 loops, best of 3: 33 ms per loop
```

I think the performance is considerably good enough.
BTW, I'm using python2.7

Comment: Good analysis, I think I know why it takes so much time, thank you!